# Error on adding image downloader to flutter app

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, flutter, dart

I've faced this issue when integrating the image_downloader plugin to the flutter app.

I've integrated firebase storage also.

Note:- The app works well with firebase storage befoe I've added image_downloader

Error:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\boood\AndroidStudioProjects\firebase_neten\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
         *********************************************************
WARNING: This version of firebase_core will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.
         *********************************************************


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':image_downloader'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: C:\Users\boood\AndroidStudioProjects\firebase_neten\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
```

My pubspec:

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
image_downloader:
firebase_storage:
image_picker:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add version to your library:

> image_downloader: ^0.19.1

Do it for all libraries in pubspec.yml file

Comment: please provide some more info, where should he edit (which file)?

Comment: @TommySM at the pubspec.yml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you always get the version correct, as of now current version is:
image_downloader: ^0.19.1

Also make sure you're adding to the right place on pubspec,
should be inside "dependencies" with the same indentation as "flutter".